# Idiomatic way to transform map in kotlin?

Tags: hashmap, kotlin

In Scala, it's just the `map` function. For example, if hashMap is a hashMap of strings, then you can do the following:

```
val result : HashMap[String,String] = hashMap.map(case(k,v) => (k -> v.toUpperCase))
```

In Kotlin, however, `map` turns the map into a list. Is there an idiomatic way of doing the same thing in Kotlin?

Comment: How about `mapKeys`, `mapValues` or applying `groupBy` to the result of simple `map`?

Comment: @yeputons. I don't know. You tell me if that's idiomatic. Feel free to add an answer

Comment: You should accept the answer from @James-bassett

Answer (score 194):

I don't think one person's opinion counts as idiomatic, but I'd probably use

```
// transform keys only (use same values)
hashMap.mapKeys { it.key.uppercase() }

// transform values only (use same key) - what you're after!
hashMap.mapValues { it.value.uppercase() }

// transform keys + values
hashMap.entries.associate { it.key.uppercase() to it.value.uppercase() }
```

Note: or `toUpperCase()` prior to Kotlin [1.5.0](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew15.html#stable-locale-agnostic-api-for-upper-lowercasing-text)

Comment: This is what I would do too although if you are only transforming values then you can use `mapValues` instead (e.g. `hashMap.mapValues { it.value.toUpperCase() }`) but I personally don't like the signature of `mapValues` because it uses `transform: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R` instead of `transform: (V) -> R` which seems to me to be inconsistent with `filterValues(predicate: (V) -> Boolean)` meaning you can't write `hashMap.mapValues(String::toUpperCase)` so I just use `hashMap.entries.associate { ... }`.

Comment: Updated to include `mapValues()` as well, thanks @mfulton26

Comment: The last line is beautiful. Thank you for this example, Kotlin is indeed awesome.

Answer (score 32):

The [`toMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html) function seems to be designed for this:

```
hashMap.map { (key, value) ->
      key.toLowerCase() to value.toUpperCase()
    }.toMap()
```

It converts `Iterable<Pair<K, V>>` to `Map<K, V>`

Comment: Here is an unnecessary transformation `toMap` 
For better performance and less code use methods from @James Bassett answer above

Comment: Not  what I needed but led me to the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @RomanNazarevych sounds like premature optimization, this option is cleaner to my personal taste

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [stdlib `mapValues` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) that others have suggested:

```kotlin
hashMap.mapValues { it.value.uppercase() }
```

or with destructuring

```kotlin
hashMap.mapValues { (_, value) -> value.uppercase() }
```

I believe this is the most idiomatic way.

Answer (score -4):

I found another variant. It seems to be more clear

```
val result = mapOf( *hashMap.map { it.key.toUpperCase() to it.value.toUpperCase() }.toTypedArray() )
```

It'll automatically infer the type of resulted map.

`.toTypedArray()` is required to use `splat(*)` operator.